# Grouping points on a line

Tags: qgis

I have a layer of centroids/points. The layer contains thousands of points. I want to group every x number of points close to each other into one group/polygon. The points are on the line, the sequence of grouped nearest neighboring points should be relative to the line, not by X and y coordinates.

[image]

I used the method of sorting points on the line, but I don't understand what to do next with it, of course you can do it all in Excel, but I would like to automate it in QGIS.

Comment: When you say you want to group every X number of points: does this mean you fix a number (X=N=3 in your example), and make group of N points?  N being a global variable? How do you need to handle lines which don't have a multiple of N points?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a layer with a given amount of lines, the following should handle the main part of your question (one required clarification is : what about the points that do not belong to lines in your screenshot, or how do you get your lines defined form a point layer)

What can be done with the geometry generator is:

- Count the amount how many groups of N (3 is taken here) can you make from the line start, for each line (using variants of `num_geometries(nodes_to_points($geometry))/3`)
- create the required amount of polygons from point groups. Points (1, 2, 3) for a line with 3 to 5 points or Points (1,2,3), (4,5,6),(7,8,9) for a line with 9 to 11 points.
- create a closed_line from this array of points, then create a polygon for each closed_line

Using the Geometry Generator in your Line Layer, you can create a Geometry Generator (type Polygon) with this definition:

```
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        generate_series(1,3*floor(num_geometries(nodes_to_points($geometry))/3),3),
            make_polygon(close_line(make_line(
                    array_foreach(generate_series(@element,@element+2,1),point_n($geometry,@element)))))))
```

The polygon size N could be set as a parameter (occurences of `3` is N, occurences of `2` is N-1)

Here's the geometry it generates:

[image]

One extra style layer also displays the point group indexes (Geometry Generator layer with $geometry as a Point geometry, Marker Symbol with `ceil(@geometry_part_num/3)` as the marker variable)

Answer (score 2):

1. On the point layer, create an attribute called `line` with Field calculator that returns the `$id` of the line the point lies on (only for points lying on a line). Use this expression: `overlay_nearest('line', $id, max_distance:=0.1)[0]`, where `line` is the name of the line layer and 0.1 a very small distance (otherwise, points will not be recognized as being on the line).
2. Create another attribute called `locate` that returns the distance along the line each point is from the line's start point. Use this expression:

   ```
    line_locate_point (
        overlay_nearest('line', $geometry, max_distance:=0.1)[0],
        $geometry
    )
   ```
3. Now group the points by assigning each point a number: first 3 points (measured from the line's start point), next 3 points etc. `line` and `locate` are the names of the attributes created above. Changing `3` in the second last line, you can define the number of points per group:

   ```
    ceil(
        (array_find (
            array_sort (array_agg ("locate", group_by:="line")),
            "locate")+1
        )/3
    )
   ```

*Per line, points are grouped in groups of 3, based on their distance from the start point along the line:*
[image]